# Django login not working after extending User class

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the following files in my Django project.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_designer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Skill(models.Model):
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skill


class Designer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)    
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery",null=True, blank=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name='skills')
    experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



class Project(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(Designer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='projects')    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    image_file_path = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project, Designer, Skill, User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import transaction


class DesignerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    skills = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Skill.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True
    )

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_designer = True
        user.save()
        designer = Designer.objects.create(user=user)
        designer.skills.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('skills'))
        return user



class ClientSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_client = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user



class DesignerSkillsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Designer
        fields = ('skills', )
        widgets = {
            'skills': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class SignUpView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'user_profile/register.html'


def home(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    skills = Skill.objects.all()  
    context = {
        'projects':projects,
        'skills':skills,        
    }
    return render(request, "user_profile/home.html", context)
class DesignerSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = DesignerSignUpForm
    template_name = 'user_profile/register_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'designer'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('profile')
@method_decorator([login_required, designer_required], name='dispatch')
class DesignerSkillsView(UpdateView):
    model = Designer
    form_class = DesignerSkillsForm
    template_name = 'user_profile/skills_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.designer

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Interests updated with success!')
        return super().form_valid(form)
class ClientSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ClientSignUpForm
    template_name = 'user_profile/register_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'client'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('profile')
def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    designer = get_object_or_404(Designer, user_id=user.id)

    skills = designer.skills.all()
    projects = designer.projects.all()
    context = {
        "designer": designer, 
        "skills": skills,
        "projects": projects,
        "username": username
    }
    return render(request, 'user_profile/designer_detail.html', context)

def project_detail(request, username, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    designer = get_object_or_404(Designer, user_id=user.id)
    project = designer.projects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {
        "project": project
    }
    return render(request, 'user_profile/project_detail.html', context)
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends 'user_profile/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="mt-5 ml-5 pl-5 pt-5">
  <h2>Sign up for a free account</h2>
  <p class="lead">Select below the type of account you want to create</p>
  <a href="{% url 'designer_register' %}" class="btn btn-lg" role="button">I'm a designer</a>
  <a href="{% url 'client_register' %}" class="btn btn-lg" role="button">I'm a client</a>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**register_form.html**

```
{% extends "user_profile/base.html" %}


{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="row mt-5 ml-5 pl-5 pt-5">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-12">
      <h2>Sign up as a {{ user_type }}</h2>
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for designers_hub project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '^x5yj)ga8oz)dp=5yf2s-lp#g+e5k=j*jn=phwtv9!u1&1drza'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'user_profile',        
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'crispy_forms',
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'designers_hub.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'user_profile.context_processors.all_skills',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'designers_hub.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_profile.User'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'

LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'


# Messages built-in framework

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
    messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
    messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
    messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
    messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
}
```

The code was working fine before I used abstractbaseuser. But after I refactored the code and tried to use the recommended AbstractBaseUser class for multiple user models, whenever I try to register a designer or client, it does not save in the database. Where is the mistake here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update your question with your settings file relevant contents ?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious wrong with your code. Does it get into the `form_valid` method at all? Can you print form.errors in the template or the console and see what it says?

Answer (score 0):

Update your settings file to use your custom user model something like this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'`

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: I had included that. I have added settings.py file. Please check.

Comment: Is it still not working ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: I found the error. It was in forms.py. I had specified required=True for skills and did not render it in register.html. So the user was not getting registered. I either have to add some skills to database or give an empty textfield and pass the values to database.